# GitHub Branch Protection: Require Status Checks for Multiple Projects in a Single Repository

Tags: git, github, repository, teamcity, pull-request

I've enjoyed using the Branch Protection options that GitHub offers. The one at the center of this question is the feature of requiring a status check prior to passing:

[image: Branch Protection]

This works great for repositories that have a single project: For a given branch (say `develop`) to be merged into, choose a build from TeamCity that requires passage for a given Pull Request before letting it in.

My current conundrum is that I have a repository that consists of multiple projects on my plate now. I've configured TeamCity to have separate build configurations for each one easily enough, giving me access to `Foo PR Build`, `Bar PR Build`, etc.

**Is there a way I can make GitHub differentiate between these, for the purposes of branch protection?** Examples like "When Project `Foo` has a PR, then GitHub should check the `Foo PR Build` branch for status in order to allow this PR to get merged into `develop`" are what I'm after here. The goal is to have a single `develop` branch for all these projects under the same repository, so creating a separate `develop` branch for each project is out of the question.

Comment: My first gut-reaction to this is to NOT have them in the same project, but use submodules for the code that each project is relying on. Here is some [supporting documentation][1] that might help you. Pay particular attention to the answer marked as correct. 

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514739/best-practice-for-git-repositories-with-multiple-projects-in-traditional-n-tier?rq=1

Comment: @BryceDrew indeed, that's the setup that is current. Some experimentation is happening in this regard to see if a single repo can be made possible. I'll give that other thread a read!